# Edge direction in a specific point

Tags: image-processing

I need to find the direction of an edge that hits a specific point in an image.

To clarify, I have an image with a white square inserted in the middle. I also have a pixel (x,y) that sits on the edge of this square (just outside the white square). I need to find the direction (angle) of any edge which "flows" into this point.

I am not very good at image processing and I am quite stuck at how to do this.

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this?

Comment: You need to google for Sobel filter.

Comment: What kind of image do you have? If it is gray image, you can compute its gradient → so by phase of gradient you'll be able to know direction of edge in any point.

Comment: Can you create a (hand-drawn) sketch or post a sample image to illustrate your problem? Especially: 1. What information do you have? 2. What information are you trying to find? 3. What information is missing to solve your problem (where exactly do you need help from us)?